# Tweepy 2.0 hanging on ssl do_handshake()

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, tweepy

I have a long running Twitter scraping script that occasionally hangs with stack traces ending in

```
"/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305: self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

My question is "why?" and "what can I do to fix it?".

It'll typically last a week or so before this happens. This last time, 3 of the 4 threads that deal with `tweepy` hung (the fourth was waiting for info from a hung thread). Strangely, there was quite a long delay between the threads hanging: firstly, the thread calling `api.followers_ids()` hung, then about 12 minutes later the thread calling `api.friends_ids()` hung, then 1 hour 12 minutes later (!) the thread calling `api.search()` hung. There were many api calls in between all of these.

I have a little code in there to dump it's stack traces when I send a `QUIT` signal, and I got something like the following for the hung threads. They are all identical from (and including) the second entry (the `tweepy/binder.py, line 185, in _call` part). The other two got there from `tweepy/cursor.py, line 85 in next` and `tweepy/cursor.py, line 60, in next`:

```
  File "myTwitterScrapingScript.py", line 245, in checkStatus
    status = api.rate_limit_status()
  File "/scratch/bin/python-virtual-environments/tweepy-2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 185, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/scratch/bin/python-virtual-environments/tweepy-2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 146, in execute
    conn.request(self.method, url, headers=self.headers, body=self.post_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)  File "/scratch/bin/python-virtual-environments/tweepy-2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 185, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/scratch/bin/python-virtual-environments/tweepy-2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 146, in execute
    conn.request(self.method, url, headers=self.headers, body=self.post_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1161, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 381, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

There were a few tweepy errors around the times the threads hung. That's not too unusual, though the number is slightly more than normal. The fourth one looks interesting though.. it happened immediately before that thread hung.

- `[Errno 110] : Connection timed out` about 7 mimutes before the last `followers_ids()` call (with many assorted api calls in between)
- `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` about 3 minutes after (again, several successful calls between)
- `[Errno 110] Connection timed out` about 1.5 minutes before the last `friends_ids()` call. This was in the `api.search()` thread, which had been waiting since about 5 minutes before the first threaad hung - a total wait of about 15 minutes.
- `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` about 2 milliseconds before the last news from the `friends_ids()` thread, and was in the same thread. The pages of friends ids just collected appear all be ok and there wasn't an error from those calls.
- `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` in the `search` thread, about 17 minutes after the `friends_ids` thread hung and nearly an hour before the `search` thread hung.
- A `Failed to send request` TweepError with no reason about 1.5 minutes later.
- 3 more reason-less `Failed to send request`'s and a `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` over the next 45 minutes.
- About 15 error-free minutes with lots of `search` and `lookup_users` calls before the `search` thread finally hung.

Comment: It looks like it's a tweepy thing: it's not setting a timeout for it's https requests. Interesting that it always fails on do_handshake().. I put in a [pull request to the tweepy repo](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/285). Havn't seen evidence of the problem, so don't know if it's fixed - once I do I'll put this up as an answer..

Comment: How many threads do you have running? There are some bottlenecks when threading SSL requests to a server. Twitter has (just as Google) a shit ton of processing power, even so SSL requires some timing and extra processing power and more often than not you will notice handshake issues or timeouts when running multiple requests like this. My best guess is that your latency on your network causes this, or the latency towards the server is to high to thread as many  threads as you might be pulling.. or it's a limitation to not get hammered?

Comment: I'd say you're right. I wasn't getting overload messages from Twitter, so it was likely a network issue closer to me I guess? Still, Tweepy should have a timeout on requests imho. The timeout messages listed came from Twitter... I havn't seen anything to suggest the same situation has reapeated since, so I'm not sure if my fix works yet. I guess I could set it up to fail, but I've other more pressing things that need doing at the moment. btw, I'm running 4 threads.

Comment: If you have a solution, I encourage you to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been with tweepy not implementing a timeout. In recent versions of tweepy, this has been fixed and this problem has not occurred since (in several months of continuous data collection).

Answer (score 0):

Please update following:

pip install --upgrade certifi